# Parameter name: userName in Experience Manager

Tags: 2013-sp1-hr1

we have enabled experience manager in SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1 and we are getting following error in event viewer when we clicked on SDL tridion button on page. Let us know where we have to pass userName ?

```
    Value cannot be empty.
Parameter name: userName.


Component: Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService Errorcode: 0 User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE  StackTrace Information Details:
   at Tridion.CommonUtilities.AssertArgumentNotNullOrEmpty(Object paramValue, String paramName)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.CoreServiceBase.Impersonate(String userName)
   at SyncInvokeImpersonate(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.CoreServiceInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

Thanks,
Ramesh

Comment: (1) Are you using *http* or *https*? 

 - (2) anything interesting in the *cd_core.log* of your **Staging website**, or *cd_core.log* of your **OData website** ?

 - (3) What are the Session Preview settings in the Session Preview tab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SDL team provided solution for this issue.

```
For this issue, can you replace the following entry in the MMC Tridion SnapIn General Settings "Urls without HTTP authentication": 

((CoreService|ImportExportService)(\d\d\d\d)?\.svc/(streamUpload|wsHttp|wsFederationHttp|mex))|(TemplateBuilder)|(.*\/Themes\/.*\.png)|(.*\/Themes\/.*\.gif)|(.*\/SiteEdit\/Views\/Bootstrap\/.*)|(ImportExportService/Client) 

with: 

((CoreService|ImportExportService)(\d\d\d\d)?\.svc/(streamUpload|wsHttp|wsFederationHttp|mex))|(TemplateBuilder)|(.*\/SiteEdit\/Views\/Bootstrap\/.*)|(ImportExportService/Client) 


Restart Tridion COM+, Tridion services and do an IIS reset. 
Clear the cache then test again and let us know the outcome.
```

Thanks,
Ramesh